# Exclude a product in cart from function woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

We have this function running where as the quantity of a product > 1, a discount fee is added to the cart. The problem is that this need to be excluded if a specific product is in cart. This is the code:

`

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'wpf_wc_add_cart_fees_by_cart_qty' );
if ( ! function_exists( 'wpf_wc_add_cart_fees_by_cart_qty' ) ) {
    /**
     * wpf_wc_add_cart_fees_by_cart_qty.
     */
    function wpf_wc_add_cart_fees_by_cart_qty( $cart ) {
        $qty = $cart->get_cart_contents_count();
        if ( $qty > 1 ) {
            $name      = 'Korting meerdere deelnemers';
            $amount    = -10;
            $taxable   = true;
            $tax_class = '';
            $cart->add_fee( $name, $amount, $taxable, $tax_class );
        }
    }
}
```

`

Now I have added a line that check if the product is in cart, but it doesnt work:

`

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'wpf_wc_add_cart_fees_by_cart_qty' );
if ( ! function_exists( 'wpf_wc_add_cart_fees_by_cart_qty' ) ) {
    /**
     * wpf_wc_add_cart_fees_by_cart_qty.
     */
     $product_id = 12345;
if( WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product_id ) ) ) {
    // Yes, it is in cart, do nothing. 
}else{
    function wpf_wc_add_cart_fees_by_cart_qty( $cart ) {
        $qty = $cart->get_cart_contents_count();
        if ( $qty > 1 ) {
            $name      = 'Korting meerdere deelnemers';
            $amount    = -10;
            $taxable   = true;
            $tax_class = '';
            $cart->add_fee( $name, $amount, $taxable, $tax_class );
         }
        }
    }
}
```

`

What am I doing wrong?

I tried to add a check if the product is in cart. If true, do nothing. If false, run the function.

Answer (score 0):

You're writing the if/else outside the function. here it the corrected code:

**Note: please make sure you have FTP access to correct the code if any fatal error comes due to any coding mistake.**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'wpf_wc_add_cart_fees_by_cart_qty' );
if ( ! function_exists( 'wpf_wc_add_cart_fees_by_cart_qty' ) ) {
    function wpf_wc_add_cart_fees_by_cart_qty( $cart ) {
        // Define product ID;
        $product_id = 12345;

        // Check if the product is not in the cart.
        if( ! $cart->find_product_in_cart( $cart->generate_cart_id( $product_id ) ) ) {
            // If not cart then run this code.
            
            $qty = $cart->get_cart_contents_count();
            if ( $qty > 1 ) {
                $name      = 'Korting meerdere deelnemers';
                $amount    = -10;
                $taxable   = true;
                $tax_class = '';
                $cart->add_fee( $name, $amount, $taxable, $tax_class );
            }
        }
    }
}
```